# Better fitness through link integration

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

Edit reviewers might have already seen it.
At the moment I am going through some questions that have bare links them.

> check this marklar on how to marklar: http://example.com/marklar/marklar.html

I think it is better for the readability to integrate those links into the text. When you write an answer, please try to do it, too.

> check out this [marklar](http://example.com/marklar/marklar.html) on how to marklar.

If you simply don't know how to do it, check the [meta help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) on StackOverflow.

I want to get some opinions if you think that this effort actually has some use or if you don't care about those links when reading a text.

There are some cases where I am not sure how or if at all to reformat, eg lists of more than one article:

> Check out all those marklar on marklar:
>
> - http://example.com/marklar1/marklar.html
> - http://example.com/marklar2/marklar.html
> - http://example.com/marklar3/marklar.html

What would be the best way to reformat those?

Comment: feel free to substitute marklar in your answers :)

Comment: Given I accepted all your edits, yes, I agree its worth your effort!

Comment: What do I know if you weren't rolling your eyes all the time and thought "Ugh, this guy again" :)

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I would slightly different is in your first example. Rather than say,

> check out this [marklar](http://example.com/marklar/marklar.html) on how to marklar.

I would rewrite it to be,

> [Marklar](http://example.com/marklar/marklar.html) has more information on how to marklar.

or something similar to that effect. When I read, "check out this marklar," I am expecting to see an additional piece of information, the link itself, since you are giving an imperative command. The embedded link works a little better when it is more "invisible" and integrated into the flow of words the other way I have written it.

Multiple links should be written out in a list as you point out. I think what you have proposed so far, and your edits are indeed helpful, would be a good effort in helping make answers and questions better to read and more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Link lists can be replaced with text links instead as well. Use something like the title of the page, the company name, etc. to make them more readable. I hate seeing lists of bare links, they're ugly, and I never know exactly what's going to happen when I click on one (especially when I'm at work). Replacing them with some text that is at least a small description of the page makes me a little less hesitant.

> Check out these other marklar on marklar:
>
> - [Some first marklar on marklar](http://example.com/marklar1/marklar.html)
> - [Another marklar on marklar](http://example.com/marklar2/marklar.html)
> - [Yet another marklar on marklar](http://example.com/marklar3/marklar.html)
> - [The last marklar on marklar](http://example.com/marklar4/marklar.html)

Comment: That makes more a little more sense. Personally I don't have a big problem with bare links as long as they are reasonable (length, semantic URI, etc). A list of links should be used with caution though; they should supplement an answer, not replace it.

Comment: I agree that they shouldn't be used as an answer.